# ¿Cómo se busca una pregunta de una persona en concreto?

Tags: soporte, búsqueda

Quiero buscar una pregunta de una persona en concreto pero, por más que lo intento, no soy capaz de dar con ella.

La respuesta de buscar en Internet no me vale, puesto que al mismo tiempo, estoy haciendo un trabajo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta pregunta es sobre el sitio en particular? para eso esta meta...

Comment: Y ahora que esta en meta, hay un buscador sobre la barra de arriba.. y tambien podes entrar al perfil del usuario y buscarla alli.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta tan pronta, problema solucionado, ya he conseguido dar con la pregunta gracias a las respuestas aquí dadas.

Comment: Otra opción es buscar el id del usuario y en la barra de busqueda añadir `user: id`. Al ponerte en la casilla de busqueda se especifica

Answer (score 2):

Como se indica en el artículo del Centro de Ayuda [¿Cómo realizo una búsqueda?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/searching), debes escribir algo así como:

```
user:id palabras o etiquetas
```

Donde `id` es el identificador del usuario, que puedes ver yendo a su perfil (por ejemplo el tuyo está en `https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142745/fernando-herrero`, luego tu id es `142745`).

Si tienes más datos, puedes acotar la búsqueda y decir cosas como:

[`user:83 is:q [bash] -[awk] created:2015 infavorites:83 closed:no answers:2..3`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A83%20is%3Aq%20%5Bbash%5D%20-%5Bawk%5D%20created%3A2015%20infavorites%3A83%20closed%3Ano%20answers%3A2..3)

Que buscaría preguntas mías con la etiqueta [bash](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) pero no [awk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) creadas en 2015, que tenga yo mismo en favoritos, no estén cerradas y tengan 2 o 3 respuestas.

Como ves, hay muchas maneras de acotar una búsqueda y es extremadamente útil.